# Issue with gradle flavor with folder name for custom src folder

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am having a requirement where i am having 4 flavor and each of this flavor there are group of two flavor have common source code while they are different only by one specific parameter defined in **buildConfigField**. Issuse i am facing is that while i am creating build for configuration let say "halfsmiledebug" i am not getting source code from halfsmile folder into main source code folder. I am getting compilation error.

My Project Structure is

```
SmileProject
            |
            |---SmileAndroidApplication
                |--src
                    |-main
                    |-halfsmile 
                    |-fullsmile
```

and there are 4 flavour

```
      -halfsmilewithyellowteeth
      -halfsmilewithwhiteteeth
      -fullsmilewithyellowteeth
      -fullsmilewithyellowteeth
```

i had defined source dir as

```
sourceSets{
            main
                    {
                        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
                    }
            halfsmilewithyellowteeth
             {
                    java.srcDirs = ['src/halfsmile/java']
              }
            halfsmilewithwhiteteeth
             {
                 java.srcDirs = ['src/halfsmile/java']
             }

            fullsmilewithyellowteeth
           {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/halfsmile/java']
            }
            fullsmilewithwhiteteeth
          {
           java.srcDirs = ['src/halfsmile/java']
           }


    productFlavors 
{ 
halfsmilewithyellowteeth
 { 
buildConfigField "String", "TYPEOFTEETH", "\"YELLOW\"" 
} 
halfsmilewithwhiteteeth 
{
 buildConfigField "String", "TYPEOFTEETH", "\"WHITE\"" 
} fullsmilewithyellowteeth
 { 
buildConfigField "String", "TYPEOFTEETH", "\"YELLOW\"" 
} 
fullsmilewithwhiteteeth 
{
 buildConfigField "String", "TYPEOFTEETH", "\"WHITE\""
 } 
}
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu : I am getting compilation error which means that java files in "halfsmilewithwhiteteeth" are not included in main folder while creating build.

Comment: If your buildConfigField has the difference for the flavors, you need to put that file into every package except for the main package. The idea behind flavors is that they are merged into one package.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I don`t want to create 4 folder for each of flavor. In my case for two flavor halfsmilewithyellowteeth and halfsmilewithwhiteteeth source code needs to remain same but only one build config paramter "teethtype" is different. If you see thats the reason for halfsmilewithyellowteeth and halfsmilewithwhiteteeth source code is defined same in build file.

Comment: If there is a difference, even slightly in the code, you need to put it in the flavor package. Check my answer.

Comment: Did it compulsory to have src code name same as of flavor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can easily implement it.

SpecificParameter.java

```
public class SpecificParameter {
    public static ParameterType getParameter() {
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

and in your buildConfigField, you can set the parameter like,

```
parameter = SpecificParameter.getParameter();
```

and put 4 SpecificParameter.java to your flavor packages. This way your flavors will work like an adapter and your build file will be single and get your parameter from your flavors.

Edit:

IF you are using the buildconfig as I understand, you can use it like this, and enums can help you with these, better than a string but thats my opinion :).

TeethType.java

```
public enum TeethType {
    YELLOW, WHITE
}

and in your gradle 
productFlavors {
    halfsmile {
        ...
    }
    fullsmile {
        ...
    }
}

buildTypes {
    whiteteeth {
        ...
        buildConfigField "...TeethType", "TEETHTYPE", "...TeethType.WHITE"
    }
    yellowteeth {
        ...
        buildConfigField "...TeethType", "TEETHTYPE", "...TeethType.YELLOW"
    }
}
```

this way you will have 2 flavors and 2 build types. In your build variants, you will see 4 kinds of them. You can access BuildConfig.TEETHTYPE anytime you want to access your type.

Comment: The code that you have written can also be achieved through productFlavors {
            halfsmilewithyellowteeth {
                buildConfigField "String", "TYPEOFTEETH", "\"YELLOW\""
            }
            halfsmilewithwhiteteeth {
               buildConfigField "String", "TYPEOFTEETH", "\"WHITE\""
            }
 fullsmilewithyellowteeth {
                buildConfigField "String", "TYPEOFTEETH", "\"YELLOW\""
            }
            fullsmilewithwhiteteeth {
               buildConfigField "String", "TYPEOFTEETH", "\"WHITE\""
            }
           
            
        }

Comment: Ahhh.. now I see lol I thought you had the parameter in some java class. So what gives the error then? Are you not accessing it through the BuildConfig class?

Comment: I am accessing it through BuildConfig only. But i am not able to get binary as i am getting compilation issue. Which tell me that there are classes which are defined in "src/halfsmile/java" are not available in main src folder.

Comment: Uhm.. you can declare like this, under BuildTypes { yellowteeth { buildConfigField "String", "TYPEOFTEETH", "YELLOW" } whiteteeth { "String", "TYPEOFTEEtH", "WHITE", this way, you will have 2 flavors and 2 build types.

Comment: Here, I edit my answer for the usage of the build types.

Comment: Did i need to remove buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }  tag ?

Comment: Debug is also a build type. If you want to use the debug build type as well, you will have 6 variants like half white, half yellow and half debug, and full white, full yellow and full debug. Other configurations like proguard files are for minifying, if you want to add them to your build types as well, you put them in your build types. Edit: I'm not sure if you can remove the debug build type. You might not but you can just ignore and not build in those two variants that i mentioned(halfsmiledebug and fullsmiledebug)